# create login validation dateofbirth as input type

Tags: html, authentication, html-input

Can any one suggest how I can create a login validation with alphanumeric characters as an input field. I am trying to use this type of the input tag, but this can only use numbers as input .

```
input type="number" name="roll number" placeholder="roll number"
```

How can I define the input field for alphanumeric input fields? example- RNO52

Comment: It seems like you are looking for validation, but no idea if Javascript or server side validation is needed. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you can just create a input type of text and write a pattern that it has to match in order to pass validation.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{3}" title="XX999" placeholder="XX999" />
```